# How to show that this operator is self adjoint? A question concerning a paper from Bertini, Giacomin and Pakdaman

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

In the paper "[Dynamical aspects of mean field plane rotators and the Kuramoto model](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.1499)" one reads
[image]

Where 
$$\langle\langle u,v\rangle\rangle = \int_S \frac{U(\theta)V(\theta)}{\hat q(\theta)}\, d \theta $$
$$U' = u,\, V' = v \text{ and }\quad \int \frac{U(\theta)}{q(\theta)}\, d\theta = 0,\int \frac{V(\theta)}{q(\theta)}\, d\theta = 0$$
and $\hat{q} $ satisfies
[image]

And where
$$
L_{\hat q} v  = \frac{1}{2} \Delta v(\theta) + K \nabla \big[ \hat{q}(\theta)\int_s \sin(\theta-\theta') v(\theta')\, d\theta' + v(\theta)\int_s \sin(\theta -\theta') \hat q (\theta')\, d \theta' \big] 
$$
This means that if  $\bar V$ is such that $\bar V ' =L_{\hat q} v $ then
$$
\bar V = \frac{1}{2} \nabla v(\theta) + K  \big[ \hat{q}(\theta)\int_s \sin(\theta-\theta') v(\theta')\, d\theta' + v(\theta)\int_s \sin(\theta -\theta') \hat q (\theta')\, d \theta' \big] 
$$
So we write
\begin{align*}
  & \langle\langle u,L_{\hat q} v\rangle\rangle = \int_S \frac{U(\theta) \bar V(\theta)}{\hat q(\theta)} \, d\theta=\\
  & \int_S \frac{U(\theta) \bigg( \frac{1}{2} \nabla v(\theta) + K  \big[ \hat{q}(\theta)\int_s \sin(\theta-\theta') v(\theta')\, d\theta' + v(\theta)\int_s \sin(\theta -\theta') \hat q (\theta')\, d \theta' \big]\bigg)}{\hat q(\theta)} d\theta\\
  &= I_1 + I_2 + I_3
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
&I_1 =   \int_S \frac{U(\theta) \frac{1}{2} \nabla v(\theta) }{\hat q(\theta)} \, d\theta\\
&I_2 =   \int_S \frac{U(\theta)  K  \hat{q}(\theta)\int_s \sin(\theta-\theta') v(\theta')\, d\theta' }{\hat q(\theta)} \, d\theta\\
&I_3 =   \int_S \frac{U(\theta)  K   v(\theta)\int_S \sin(\theta -\theta') \hat q (\theta')\, d \theta' }{\hat q(\theta)} \, d\theta\\
\end{align*}

Now, let's do integration by parts on each of the above terms:

\begin{align*}
  I_1 &=   \int_S \frac{U(\theta) \frac{1}{2} \nabla v(\theta) }{\hat q(\theta)} \, d\theta\\
  & = -\int_S \frac{u(\theta) \frac{1}{2} v(\theta) }{\hat q(\theta)} \, d\theta +\int_S  \frac{\hat q'(\theta)u(\theta) \frac{1}{2}  v(\theta) }{\hat q^2(\theta)} \, d\theta\\
  & = \int_S \frac{\nabla u(\theta) \frac{1}{2} V(\theta) }{\hat q(\theta)} \, d\theta -\int_S \frac{u(\theta) \frac{1}{2} v(\theta)\hat q'(\theta) }{\hat q^2(\theta)} \, d\theta  +\int_S  \frac{\hat q'(\theta)u(\theta) \frac{1}{2}  v(\theta) }{\hat q^2(\theta)} \, d\theta\\
  & =  \int_S \frac{\nabla u(\theta) \frac{1}{2} V(\theta) }{\hat q(\theta)} \, d\theta
\end{align*}

Now we move on to the term $I_2$

\begin{align*}
  I_2 &=  \int_S \frac{U(\theta)  K  \hat{q}(\theta)\int_S \sin(\theta-\theta') v(\theta')\, d\theta' }{\hat q(\theta)} \, d\theta\\
   &=  \int_SU(\theta) K \int_S    \sin(\theta-\theta') v(\theta')\, d\theta'  \, d\theta\\
   &=  \int_Su(\theta) K\int_S    \cos(\theta-\theta') v(\theta')\, d\theta'  \, d\theta\\
   &=  \int_Su(\theta)K  \int_S  - \sin(\theta-\theta') V(\theta')\, d\theta'  \, d\theta\\
   &=  \int_SV(\theta') K \int_S   \sin(\theta'-\theta) u(\theta)\, d\theta  \, d\theta'\\
\end{align*}

Now, $I_3$ (And here is the problem!)
\begin{align*}
I_3 &=   \int_S \frac{U(\theta)  K   v(\theta)\int_S \sin(\theta -\theta') \hat q (\theta')\, d \theta' }{\hat q(\theta)} \, d\theta\\
\end{align*}
We would like to show that
$$
I_3 =   \int_S \frac{V(\theta)  K   u(\theta)\int_S \sin(\theta -\theta') \hat q (\theta')\, d \theta' }{\hat q(\theta)} \, d\theta
$$

For this, write $$H(\theta) =  \frac{K  \int_S \sin(\theta -\theta') \hat q (\theta')\, d \theta' }{\hat q(\theta)}$$ 
and note that
\begin{align*}
  I_3 &=   \int_S U(\theta) H(\theta)   v(\theta) \, d\theta\\
  & = \int_S H(\theta)\big[(U(\theta)V(\theta))' - u(\theta)V(\theta)\big] \, d\theta\\
  & = \int_S H(\theta)(U(\theta)V(\theta))' \,d(\theta) - \int_S H(\theta) u(\theta)V(\theta) \, d\theta\\
  & =- \int_S H'(\theta)(U(\theta)V(\theta)) \,d(\theta) - \int_S H(\theta) u(\theta)V(\theta) \, d\theta\\  
\end{align*}
Now, we wish to compute $H'(\theta)$. The computation follows:
\begin{align}
  H'(\theta) &= \big(\frac{K}{\hat q(\theta)}    \int_S \sin(\theta -\theta') \hat q (\theta')\, d \theta'\big)' \nonumber\\
  & =\frac{K}{\hat q(\theta)} \bigg[-\frac{\hat q'(\theta)}{\hat q(\theta)} \int_S \sin(\theta -\theta') \hat q (\theta')\, d \theta' + \int_S \cos(\theta -\theta') \hat q (\theta')\, d \theta'\bigg]\label{eq:pre}
\end{align}
By relation (1.16) (in the paper) (remember that $C=0$ in 1.16)
\begin{equation}
  -\frac{\hat q'(\theta)}{\hat q(\theta)} = 2K \int_S \cos(\theta -\theta') \hat q (\theta')\, d \theta'
  \label{1.16}
\end{equation}
Substituting, yields
\begin{align*}
  H'(\theta) & =\frac{K}{\hat q(\theta)}\int_S\cos(\theta -\theta') \hat q (\theta')\, d \theta' \big[-2K \int_S \sin(\theta -\theta') \hat q (\theta')\, d \theta' + 1\big]
\end{align*}

But how do we arrive at the desired result?

Comment: You mention a certain (1.16) but where is it ?

Comment: IMHO, your text is much too long. Try to concentrate your question.

Comment: I don't see how I could make it shorter, without leaving the main ideas behind. 1.16 is in the paper, I tried not to overload the text with further references.